# The method CreateDefaultView () is not called in devexpress GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have inherited a devexpress GridControl, following all steps from [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A859.aspx).

There is only one problem,
the method CreateDefaultView() is never called.

This is the code:

```
public partial class gttDXGridControl : GridControl
{
    public gttDXGridControl() : base()
    { }

    protected override void RegisterAvailableViewsCore(InfoCollection collection)
    {
        base.RegisterAvailableViewsCore(collection);
        collection.Add(new gttDXGridViewInfoRegistrator());
    }

    //this event is not called for some reason...
    protected override BaseView CreateDefaultView()
    {
        gttDXGridView gridView = CreateView("gttGridView") as gttDXGridView;
        // would like to initialize stuff here...
        return gridView;
    }
}

public partial class gttDXGridViewInfoRegistrator : DevExpress.XtraGrid.Registrator.GridInfoRegistrator
{
    public override string ViewName { get { return "gttGridView"; } }
    public override BaseView CreateView(GridControl grid) { return new gttDXGridView(grid as GridControl); }
    public override BaseViewInfo CreateViewInfo(BaseView view) { return new gttDXGridViewInfo(view as gttDXGridView); }
    public override BaseViewHandler CreateHandler(BaseView view) { return new gttDXGridHandler(view as gttDXGridView); }

}

public partial class gttDXGridViewInfo : GridViewInfo
{
    public gttDXGridViewInfo(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView) : base(gridView)
    { }

    public override int CalcRowHeight(Graphics graphics, int rowHandle, int min, int level, bool useCache, GridColumnsInfo columns)
    {
        return base.CalcRowHeight(graphics, rowHandle, MinRowHeight, level, useCache, columns);
    }

    public override int MinRowHeight
    {
        get { return base.MinRowHeight - 2; }
    }
}
```

This event is the place to be for initializing properties of the GridView, but its just never called.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is called when `MainView` property is `null`. It means that this event will be called when you add new `gttGridControl` to your form in design time or in runtime.
Here is example for runtime:

```
var gridControl = new gttDXGridControl();

gridControl.Width = 100;
gridControl.Height = 100;

Controls.Add(gridControl); // => Here this event will be invoked.
```

Comment: So when I drop this control on a form this event should be called ? If so, then why is it not called in my gttDXGridControl ?

Comment: @GuidoG How you are checking this?

Comment: I have set a breakpoint in all my methods, the only method where the application does not stops is in this method.

Comment: @GuidoG Breakpoints are not working during design time. You can check it if you place something like `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");` inside your `CreateDefaultView` method.

Comment: I also had a line of code there to initialize a property of the gridview, this also did not happen

Comment: in runtime all this code also executed when loading the form, there the breakpoints do work, every breakpoint is called, except for this one

Comment: yes, as I already explained. I test all in runtime its the only way you can use breakpoints. Also, in the desinger.cs there is line of code : this.panelGrid.Controls.Add(this.gttDXGridList);

Comment: @GuidoG I have copypasted your code into new project and used my code in `Button.Click` event. Breakpoint is executed.

Comment: Have you inherited a new GridControl from devexpress GridControl like I did ?

Comment: but the breakpoint is only executed in the button click, not when the code from the designer.cs is executed ? Its exact the same code, so why does one gets executed and the other is not ?

Comment: @GuidoG Find in your `designer.cs` something like `gttDXGridControl1.MainView = gttGridView1;`, comment it and try to run.

Comment: but the GridControl in designtime now has a GridView in stead of a gttGridView.

Comment: hmm, after a second build the GridControl has the correct gttGridView in stead of the standard GridView. So now I now that this has something to do with my problem, the quesion is now, how to get around this. When dropping my GridControl on a form, this line of code is generated by visual studio.

Comment: @GuidoG The question is what are you really trying to achieve? There is possibility that `CreateDefaultView` method is not what you are looking for.